# The "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier" error in c++

Tags: c++

I've decided to implement some design patterns in C++ just as an exercise and created a certain project architecture, the thing is that I want my patterns to live inside the `patterns` directory and in different files. For example `SimpleFactoryPattern` should be put in the `simplefactory.h` file. The code looks like this:

```
class SimpleAutoFactory {
    public:
        SimpleAutoFactory() {};
        ~SimpleAutoFactory() {};
        SharedInterfaces::IAuto *getAutoModel(EModel model) {
            switch (model) {
                case EModel::EFiat:
                    return new SharedModels::Fiat;

                case EModel::ELamborghini:
                    return new SharedModels::Lamborghini;

                case EModel::EMaserati:
                    return new SharedModels::Maserati;

                default: throw CommonExceptions::unknownModelException;
            }
        }
};
```

Then I simply include this piece in the main.cpp and run `make && make run` to compile and execute the whole thing. The problem is that my linter yields errors saying that it doesn't know where the `SharedInterfaces` namespace comes from and so on. I suspect there must be something wrong with the structure of the project. 
I'm sort of new to C++ but as far as I know we only declare things in headers and execute stuff in cpps. If I import, that's, include the required headers in my `simplefactory.cpp` file I face the redefinition error.
What is the right way to handle this in C++?

Comment: *If I import* -- The term "import" is not used in C++ in this way.  All an `#include` does is literally copy and paste the code from the file in the spot where the `#include` is stated.  Nothing more, nothing less.  If you think `#include` is doing some sort of extra "stuff" like in Java or some other language, you're mistaken.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah meaning that I could pile all that code into one file and it would still make no difference for the compiler, I understand. So it's just a linter problem then, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You header file should only have declarations, something like this:

simplefactory.h:

```
#pragma once

// here you should also include the header files where your other classes (IAuto, Fiat etc) are declared

class SimpleAutoFactory {
    public:
        SharedInterfaces::IAuto *getAutoModel(EModel model); // only declaration, no definition
};
```

Then, in your cpp files you define your functions:

simplefactory.cpp:

```
#include "simplefactory.h"

SharedInterfaces::IAuto *SimpleAutoFactory::getAutoModel(EModel model) {
            switch (model) {
                case EModel::EFiat:
                    return new SharedModels::Fiat;

                case EModel::ELamborghini:
                    return new SharedModels::Lamborghini;

                case EModel::EMaserati:
                    return new SharedModels::Maserati;

                default: throw CommonExceptions::unknownModelException;
            }
        }
```

Then you can either compile these files together with your main, or compile these files as a static or shared library and pass it to the linker.

Comment: Oh I see, it clearly makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @igor If this post answers your question, you can press the green tick on the left to mark your problem as solved.